# discord.py send a message if author isnt in a voice channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want my bot to send a message if im not in a voice channel when i type a command.

Heres my current code:

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel 
    if channel:
        await channel.connect() 
        await ctx.send('Joining voicechat.')
    elif channel is None:
        await ctx.send('You have to be in a voice channel first.')
```

It joins and sends a message when i'm in a voice channel, but when i'm not, it returns this error in terminal:

`Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Member.voice` will be None, you need to check that

Below is the revised code:

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice
    if channel:
        await channel.channel.connect() 
        await ctx.send('Joining voicechat.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You have to be in a voice channel first.')
```